# for any integer $n\ge2$, consider the group ${\bf Z}_{p^n}\oplus{\bf Z}_p$. Determine the number of cyclic subgroups of order $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, direct-product

I know ${\bf Z}_p\oplus{\bf Z}_p$ has a cyclic group of p+1 order p. but what about when it's n? (p is prime)

Comment: Please show us your thoughts about this problem. If you are completely stuck, just reviewing the result when $n = 1$ could be of use.

Comment: The only (nonnegative) integers not exceeding 2 are 0, 1, and 2. So I guess your question is just about ${\bf Z}_{p^2}\oplus{\bf Z}_p$? Is $p$ supposed to be a prime? If so, this should be edited into the body of your question.

Comment: yes p is prime... maybe knowing Z$_(p^2)$ ⊕Z$_p$ will help with replacing the 2 with n

Comment: But you're only interested in $n\le2$, right? Anyway, can you work out the number of elements of order $p$ in ${\bf Z}_{p^2}$?

Comment: its n ≥ 2, and I had ($p^3$-1)/(p-1)= $p^2$+p+1 is that right?

Comment: Good of you to edit the title, finally. The number of elements of order $p$ in ${\bf Z}_{p^2}$ is certainly not $p^2+p+1$.

Comment: Seen my answer, rich?

Comment: Are you still here, rich?

Answer (score 0):

The elements of ${\bf Z}_{p^n}\oplus{\bf Z}_p$ are the ordered pairs $(a,b)$ with $a$ in ${\bf Z}_{p^n}$ and $b$ in ${\bf Z}_p$. Assuming here and throughout that $n\ge1$, the number of elements of order 1 or $p$ in ${\bf Z}_{p^n}$ is $p$, so the number of elements of order 1 or $p$ in ${\bf Z}_{p^n}\oplus{\bf Z}_p$ is $p^2$. Exactly one of these elements has order 1, so there are $p^2-1$ elements of order $p$ in ${\bf Z}_{p^n}\oplus{\bf Z}_p$.

Each subgroup of order $p$ contains $p-1$ of these elements of order $p$, and each element of order $p$ is in exactly one subgroup of order $p$, so the number of subgroups of order $p$ is $(p^2-1)/(p-1)$, which is $p+1$.